# Where can I find a complete list of web element names

Tags: website-design, user-centered-design

I found some names of web element like "pricing table", "slider", "navigation menu" and "subscribe form".

What is their general category name and where can I find a complete list of names of the other web elements in the same category with the elements I mentioned above?

Comment: Does this help: [smashing mag](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/21/web-design-industry-jargon-glossary-and-resources/), its pretty exhaustive.

Comment: no, but thank you for replying to my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called User Interface Design Patterns (or simply UI Patterns)

Searching for this on the web will give enough resources. One of the first you will come across is ui-patterns.com where [this page](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns) shows a list of patterns with an explanation and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first one that comes to mind is the [Glossary of UI Terminology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226821(v=vs.85).aspx) by Microsoft, but you have the [Android Glossary](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/glossary.html) or if you have an Apple developer ID, you can log to https://idmsa.apple.com and download their glossaries in XML format. They all differ in contents and organization of their content, and also they call some things differently, but between the 3 of them, you can get the most comprehensive list of web element names